# Linux (on a BlueHost server) cron job stopped passing argument

Tags: php, linux, cron

The cronjob below has been running on a Bluehost Linux/Apache machine without issue for 3+ years until last night.

```
* * * * * php -q /home/siteID/public_html/path/to/cron.php --f=dirclean
```

The argument " --f=dirclean " is no longer being passed.  The cron.php script accepts parameters as follows:

```
if(isset($argv) || isset($_GET['f'])){ //etc... }
```

If I drop the " -- " argument is passed.  Unclear why this cronjob was written in this manner originally.

Of course, Bluehost tech support states no support for cron and we didn't change anything.

Any ideas about what went wrong and how we might fix it?

Comment: I'm not aware that php has ever converted command line arguments into $_GET stuff. cli has always been processed via argc/argv.

Comment: My guess is the $_Get part of the signature was written this way to facilitate testing away from cron.  The issue appears to be the two dashes in front of the "f".  Looking at my Linux manual and don't see anything on this...

Comment: well, for cli it'd be all in argv, so do `var_dump($argv)` in the script and see what arrives. php hasn't changed command line processing interfaces at all, so there's no reason for (possibly) a php version upgrade to break something as simple as this.

Comment: var_dump($argv);  and var_dump($_GET['f']); both return NULL.  If I take the -- off the cronjob,   var_dump($_GET['f']); returns "dirclean".

Comment: `which php`? maybe you're running the php binary directly, but some shell script instead, and that script is stripping off arguments.

Comment: php version 5.4.43

Comment: naw, I mean run the command `which php` at the cli, so you can see which binary/script is actually being run. e.g. it comes back as /usr/local/bin/php, and that happens to be a shell script that runs the real binary at /opt/blah/blah/php5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The argument " --f=dirclean " is no longer being passed. The cron.php script accepts parameters as follows:

Do you have access to the cron logs on the server or you're using a shared hosting?

If you'd not then all you can is try to test if your PHP file launch at all and then edit your script. Maybe you can try to use command prompt arguments instead.

Take a look [here](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/view/top-4-cron-mistakes.html) for more info about debugging cron jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon additional error messages, clearly, a change was made on BH side.  Rewrote the cron script to accommodate the new "lessor" capability...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass arguments to your script as shown here instead:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php